# Parametric curve problem by expressing $dy/dt$ in terms of $dx/dt$

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding parametric curve, I'm new to this material so how do I approach this type of question?

Suppose that $xy = 4$. Express $dy/dt$ in terms of $dx/dt$ when $x = 8$ and $y = 1/2$.

Comment: Use LaTeX, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're given the equation $xy = 4$. If you take the derivative of **both** sides with respect to $t$, you have: $$\begin{align}{d\over dt}(xy) &= {d\over dt}(4)\\ {dx\over dt}y + x{dy\over dt} &= 0 \tag{Product rule on LHS} \\ \implies x{dy\over dt}&= - {dx\over dt}y \\ \implies {dy\over dt}&=-{dx\over dt}{y\over x}. \tag{Assume $x\ne 0$}\end{align}$$

Since we know that $x = 8$ and $y = {1\over 2}$, we simply plug these into the above to yield: $$\begin{align}{dy\over dt} &= -{dx\over dt}{1/2\over 8} \\&=-{1\over 16}{dx\over dt}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative of the equation and using the fact that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(xy)=\frac{dx}{dt}y+x\frac{dy}{dt}$$
yields
$$\frac{dx}{dt}y+x\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$
(You get zero on the right-hand side since the derivative of a constant is zero).

Answer (score 0):

Start with $y=\frac{4}{x}$ and differentiate by $t$: $\large{\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{4}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}}$. Now substitute value of $x$ (note that you get relation between rates of growth of $x$ and $y$ at the given point).